# With (a) consistently high Net Promoter Score/scores?

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> Lead and build proof-of-concepts for various enterprises utilizing our services with **a consistently high Net Promoter Score (NPS)**.

> Lead and build proof-of-concepts for various enterprises utilizing our services with **consistently high Net Promoter Scores (NPSs)**.

May I know which one is grammatical and idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much no difference between the two sentences, both are grammatical as well. They are both idiomatic in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

*Net Promoter Score (NPS)* and *Net Promoter Scores (NPSs)* are proper nouns.  This way of representing singular and plural proper nouns is fine, as @DialFrost has answered.

The two examples each consist of
a compound verb *Lead and build*, a noun phrase *proof-of-concepts* and two preposition phrases.

They are not complete sentences and hence should not start with capital letters and end with full stops.